# Capturing and Bubbling using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-bubbling, propagation

I am new to jQuery and I‘m trying to understand the concept of capturing and bubbling.

I have read a lot of articles, but most of them described event propagation for Javascript.

Lets assume we have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="outer">
    outer
    <div id="inner">
        inner
    </div>
</div>
```

Capturing is the phase where we go down the DOM elements and bubbling is when we go up.

In Javascript you can decide which way to follow (using true or false parameters):

```
element.addEventListener('click', doSomething, true) --> capture phase
element.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false) --> bubble phase
```

Is there anything similar for jQuery to denote which way to follow other than the JavaScript way?

Also does jQuery uses a default phase? For example bubble?

Because i used the following code to test this:

**css**

```
<style>
    div {
        border: 1px solid green;
        width: 200px;
    }
</style>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div').click(function(){
            $(this).animate({'width':'+=10px'},{duration: 3000})
        });
    });
</script>
```

It appears that when I click on the outer div, only that div animates to a larger div. When I click to the inner div both divs animate to larger divs.

I don’t know if I am wrong, but this test shows that the default browser propagation method is bubble.

Please correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: @adeneo How does that question address what jQuery does? The OP seems to understand what bubbling and capture are, he just wants to know how it relates to jQuery.

Comment: @Barmar - wasn't sure, which is why I didn't close, I thought maybe the OP needed an explanation of that capture was, as it doesn't really relate to jQuery at all since jQuery hardcodes 'false' for addEventlistener when it's called, and there's no option to change it as capture is generally never used.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

jQuery only uses event bubbling. If you want to add an event handler that uses the capturing model, you have to do it explicitly using `addEventListener`, with the third argument `true` as you show in the question.

Answer (score 7):

Event bubbling which will start executing from the innermost element to the outermost element.

Event Capturing which will start executing from the outer element to the innermost element.

But jQuery will use event bubbling. We can achieve event capturing with:

```
$("body")[0].addEventListener('click', callback, true);
```

The 3rd parameter in the addEventListener which will tell the browser whether to take event bubbling or event capturing.

By default it is false.

If it is false then it will take event bubbling.
If it is true then it will take event capturing.

Comment: You can apply $("body").get(0) too it's the same as $("body")[0] which lets you use jquery to work with javascript native features.

Answer (score 5):

Question and answers live with the following misconception: that the browser does either capture or bubble.

**Truth is: the browser does always both, capture and bubble, on every click, in that order.**

> Is there anything similar for jQuery to denote which way to follow other than the JavaScript way?
>   Also does jQuery uses a default phase? For example bubble?

jQuery has no event phases. The DOM has. And the DOM does always both.
But jQuery registers handlers only to the bubble phase. There is no jQuery way to register to the capture phase, so bubble registration is not a default, it is the only way (with jQuery).

> I don’t know if I am wrong, but this test shows that the default browser propagation method is bubble.

You are wrong, if I’m allowed to say. When you click on the outer div, capture happens, until it reaches the outer div, then bubble... It just does not go any deeper than the actual target of the event.

If you click the inner div, capture passes the outer div, but no handler is registered there for that phase, then it reaches the target, and on the way back up (bubble) it triggers the outer div handler.—I haven’t run your code, but it would be hard to tell which one happened first (the inner is first).

*(Note: once the target is reached, the phase is actually called “target phase” and handlers are called independent of which phase they registered for (in registration order, btw).)*

Answer (score 1):

Every `Event` is going first through "capturing" phase and then through "bubbling" phase.

For instance, when user clicks on `<a>`, all event handlers bound using "capturing" (third argument in `addEventListener` method set to `true`, not supported in jQuery) are called starting from outermost `<html>` all the way down to the link. Then, the "bubbling" phase starts and all event handlers using "bubbling" (supported in jQuery) are called the opposite way - from link back to the `<html>`.

You can try it on your own, firing this code in developer tools and clicking anywhere on your site.

```
document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(it => {
   it.addEventListener("click", function() {console.log("capturing: ", it)}, true); 
   it.addEventListener("click", function() {console.log("bubbling: ", it)}, false); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The event is triggered in event bubbling on the element on to which the user has clicked,and unless we call .stopPropagation() on the event object the event is then triggered all the way up the DOM.
Default is event bubbling set in Jquery in order to use Capture ypu need to set parameter as true in .addEventListner