# Listening to the focus event in angular using $on

Tags: angularjs

I am using the swiper widget by [Idangero](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/#.Vqiziip96Uk), which allows me to pagify a form. However, since it loads all the controls up front, it is possible to tab into a field on the next page. I want to prevent this and I have found this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6rtskL5g/1/) that changes the page when tabbing.

It, however, uses regular javascript to listen to the focus event `$('form')[0].addEventListener('focus'...` I want to convert this to a more angular version using the $rootscope.$on (I also want it to blur out of the field instead of changing the page, but I think I can handle that) anyone know how to do this?

I'd rather not use the ng-focus directive because then I have to add it to the controls at the bottom and top of every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General Answer for Angular events**

[`$rootScope.$on`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on) is not used for element events - it is for events broadcast within your scope, using [`$rootScope.$boradcast`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) or [`$rootScope.$emit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit).

If you want to listen to a `focus` event on an element, you can use the `on()` method in [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). This is almost identical to the equivalent [jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
angular.element(document).find('form').on('focus', function() {
    // do something ...
});
```

**Specific Explanation for `form.onfocus`**

In your specific case however, the code is using event capture (`addEventListener('focus, function() {}, true)'`), rather than bubbling (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616720/1901857) for more info). This is required because `form` elements do not have their own `focus` event, only the input elements do, so they will not handle `focus` events bubbled up from the inputs.

Unfortunately jQuery (and hence Angular) only supports event bubbling (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24585928/1901857) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17249184/1901857)). A further  issue is that jqLite built in to Angular does not support [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), where as full jQuery does.

This means your options are either:

1. Add full jQuery to your page so you can use a delegated event:

   ```
   $('form').on('focus', ':input', function() {
       // do something
   });
   ```
2. Use the vanilla JavaScript `addEventListener` with `useCapture` as you are now:

   ```
   $('form')[0].addEventListener('focus', function() {
       // do something
   }, true);
   ```

The `$('form')` code suggests you already have full jQuery installed, so options 1 should work for you.

Comment: In the end I used $window.addEventListener, but this is what I needed thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays it's best to just use [ng-focus](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus)