# Catch the load event from iframes, using jQuery delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, event-delegation

I want to catch the `load` even of *any* iframe which is appended on the document at some point after loading the page.

I tried using `on("load", "iframe", fn)`, but that doesn't seem to do it:

```js
function addIframe() {
  $("<iframe src='https://example.com'>").appendTo($("body"))
}

// This does not work
$(document).on("load", "iframe", function() {
  alert("loaded, caught via delegation")
})

setTimeout(function() {
  addIframe()
  // This works
  $("iframe").on("load", function() {
    alert("Loaded, caught via direct selection")
  })
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

While `$("iframe").on("load", fn)`, right after appending the iframe works, delegation on the `document` doesn't work.

How can we detect any iframe load from the page using delegation?

Comment: An iframe is not the same as an img, but the solution described there works in your situation as well.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Interesting, [this] works! Thanks! But, how would the jQuery way look in that case? I played [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w27yn1go/6/).

Comment: I googled `jquery usecapture` and found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585698/capturing-and-bubbling-using-jquery . Seems impossible with jQuery, have to use `addEventListener`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yeah... found the same. Anyways, addEventListener seems to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can we detect any iframe load from the page using delegation?

Unfortunately, It is not possible catching the iframe load events via jQuery delegation.

Comment: And it is not possible because LOAD event not bubbles.